# Composer.phar cannot install dependencies

Tags: php, symfony

I have been trying to install all dependencies using phar but it always give me an error

```
[ErrorException]                                       
  rtrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

I have been struggling with this for a while and would appreciate any help.

My Php version (From phpinfo()) is Php Version 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.6

additional info for error: pastebin.com/V2w6Cg69

with --verbose : http://www.pastebin.com/qL0RHA2a

Comment: You problem can't be diagnosed, since none of the code you've pasted actually shows an rtrim() call.

Comment: added more http://www.pastebin.com/qL0RHA2a  , I've raised this issue to the developer on their IRC channel. They are able to reproduce it and working on it. I will update with the solution, once the developer are done with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember this occured when I introduced the Config class and was fixed shortly after. Updating to the latest composer version should fix it.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update this question, you have introduced the fix already